# GitLab PyTest just won't discover my modules

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest

I'm trying to run PyTests on a GitLab CI/CD instance, but even though everything runs just fine locally, no matter what I do, I can't seem to make GitLab discover my modules. How can I make sure my modules are discovered without using relative paths? I specifically created the `setup.py` so that everything is registered correctly. During installation all the modules and packages even show up on GitLab:

```
...
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
['hr_datapool', 'hr_datapool.external_workforce']
running bdist_wheel
...
```

In my `tests.py` file I tried importing with both `from hr_datapool.external_workforce import misc_tools` and `from external_workforce import misc_tools`, but still, on GitLab I get the error that either `hr_datapool` or `external_workforce` is not found:

> ```
> ==================================== ERRORS ====================================
> _____ ERROR collecting hr_datapool/external_workforce/tests/test_tools.py ______
> ImportError while importing test module '/builds/my.profile/hr-datapool/hr_datapool/external_workforce/tests/test_tools.py'.
> Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
> Traceback:
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> hr_datapool/external_workforce/tests/test_tools.py:9: in <module>
>     from external_workforce import misc_tools
> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'external_workforce'
> ```

My project has this folder structure:

```
.
|__ requirements.txt
    setup.py
    hr_datapool
    |__ __init__.py
        external_workforce
        |__ __init__.py
            misc_tools.py
            tests
            |__ test_tools.py
        |__ other_module
            ...
```

I'm trying to run the tests on GitLab, so I created a pipeline:

```
image: python:3.9.7

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python --version  # For debugging
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
  script:
    - pytest --pyargs hr_datapool #- python setup.py test

run:
  script:
    - python setup.py bdist_wheel
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*.whl
```

And then since I want to make sure all the packages and modules are easily available, I set up a setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()
    for req in ['wheel', 'bar']:
        requirements.append(req)
    
setup(
   name='hr-datapool',
   version='0.1',
   ...
   packages=find_packages(), 
   install_requires=requirements,
)
```

Comment: Try running `pip install .` before running `pytest`.

Comment: I tried `python setup.py bdist_wheel` but didn't help... Does `pip` install stuff differently?

Comment: That command just builds the package, it does not install it.

Comment: you need to install your module before running fo to the setup.py path and `pip install .` The command which you said you tried creats dist and wheels does not install your package